# CodeIgniter - only connect to database if there is a query to run

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

At the moment I load the database class in my autoload which automatically creates a connection to mysql. If there are no queries it will have still created a connection.

For performance I only want to connect to mysql if a query has been run.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

I am thinking of writing a model function that all queries run through which detects if the database has been connected to or not, and simply calls `$this->load->database()` if not before running `$this->db->query()`.

The problem with this is that I would have to change all of my `$this->db->query()` references in my code which is a pain.

Ideally I would like to extend the `$this->db->query()` function to support this.

Any ideas?

Comment: This would only be useful if you have many pages that don't need a DB query. Or if you're using caching heavily

Comment: Not sure what the advantage would be here, while you have a connection to the DB, it is only active when used anyways.  Its like autoloading html, url, and other librarys. They are not a performance hit until called on to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the autoinit property of your database config

```
$db['mydb']['autoinit'] = false;
```

This will cause you database class to not initialize (which include connecting to the server) when instantiated, it will instead happen when the first query occurs.

See [the database configuration page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)